# How to implement plateau limit histogram equalization algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have been trying to implement a simple and short algorithm.  i compare my result's histogram with original result's histogram and there is always a huge difference.
[image: histogram of difference]

i reviewed my code again and again. but i couldn't see what is the problem. i posted steps and my try. where is my mistake?

[image: step1]

```
histogram_of_image = imhist(input_image);
modified_histogram = zeros(1,256);
modified_histogram(1:256)  = (log(histogram_of_image(1:256)+(a))).^(beta);
```

[image: step 2]

```
these_elements_are_not_zero = modified_histogram~= 0;
sum2 = sum(modified_histogram(these_elements_are_not_zero));
cnt2 = size(these_elements_are_not_zero,2);
tcl = sum2/cnt2;
clipped_histogram = zeros(1,256);
for i=1:256
    if((modified_histogram(i)) >= tcl)
    clipped_histogram(i) = tcl;    
    else 
    clipped_histogram(i) = (modified_histogram(i));   
    end
end
```

[image: step 3]

```
PDa = zeros(1,256);
PDa = clipped_histogram / (sum(clipped_histogram)); 
CDa = zeros(1,256);  %create CDa in formula
CDa(1) = PDa(1) ;
for i=2:256
     CDa(i) =  PDa(i) +  CDa(i-1);  
end
value_after_enhancement =  zeros(1,256); 
value_after_enhancement = (255 * CDa); 
b=uint8(0);
output_image=zeros(width,height);
output_image =   value_after_enhancement(input_image+1);
figure;imshow(uint8(output_image));
original_result=imread('testsonuc.bmp');
original_result=double(rgb2gray(original_result));
image_of_dif= zeros(width,height);
figure;imshow(uint8(original_result));
```

Comment: these_elements_are_not_zero will be all the elements on your modified histogram, because you in worst case scenario if the original histogram is 0, then the modified histogram value will be 0.4805, maybe you mean that isn't zero in the original histogram ?

Comment: when i change code for the original histogram. i see a worse result than this.

Comment: as I understand you want your histogram to look like the histogram while using histeq() instruction, distributed all over the bins, not mostly on the last bin, right ?

Comment: yes right. algorithm also tells that, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct except a small detail in plotting the results, you should convert your output image from double to unsigned integer.`output_image = uint8(output_image);`

```
%value_after_enhancement =  zeros(1,256);
value_after_enhancement = (255 * CDa)+1;
%b = uint8(0);
%output_image = zeros(width,height);
output_image = value_after_enhancement(input_image);
output_image = uint8(output_image);
%dif_image = output_image ./ input_image;
%===================================================================
figure('Name','Algorithm Result','NumberTitle','off');
subplot(211);
imshow(output_image);
subplot(212);
Out_Hist = imhist(output_image);
plot(Out_Hist);
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately there is still a difference histogram. why it can be happen?[link](https://imgur.com/a/QIJT6o7)

Comment: of course there will be a difference, but a slight difference, because you do a histogram processing, you apply the transfer function to enhance your image, that means you increase your image contrast, increasing contrast means using unused bins in your histogram (on the borders near 1 and 256), and you will spread unused bins among your histogram bins in the middle , so of course it will change !

Comment: no, i mean i compare my result with original output. i don't mean input

Comment: Ok I see, maybe because we are using different images, I'm using Lena.png here

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/6VdRkQy) i use original output and input  image from, [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8284291)   research paper.

Comment: I have to read that paper thoroughly to see other small details, unfortunately I don't have account on IEEExplore website to read that paper and give you a feedback, because what you have implemented so far is identical to what's written up. unless there is extra details or further post-processing

Comment: there is no more in proposed algorithm. i don't have original data, i extract them using adobe. is it can be the reason of difference histogram?

Comment: If the spatial resolution is different of course the histogram will be different, histogram is just a representation of the discreet grayscale level counts on your image, it depends on pixels count, and pixels graylevels

Comment: yeah, but size of the images are same and both of [them](https://imgur.com/a/vc4ygKQ) are uint8

Comment: See this research please it looks like this is the original paper [link](http://www.jprr.org/index.php/jprr/article/download/617/218)

Comment: I added some lines to your code, so you can see more results and compare the shapes of your CDF PDF with other's results [link](https://github.com/bhomaidan1990/Palmyra/blob/master/IR_Image_Hist_Equlaization.m)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204968/discussion-between-beyblade41-and-belal-homaidan).